2 websites, 2 DNS, 1 Nginx server, sharing a port - How do I direct requests to the correct server block?
I have one website "www.alpha.com" registered with Cloudflare, with SSL through Cloudflare, which I host on my own server (Nginx on Linux Debian). I'm trying to add a 2nd website "www.beta.com", which is registered with Google Domains.
I added a A record to Google Domains pointing to my IP address. I added the website source files to /var/www/html, added a 2nd server block in a separate file in /etc/nginx/sites-available, and a symbolic link in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.
URL for "beta" serves the content for "alpha". I can get it to serve beta if I put the server block directly into nginx.conf, but I need 2 separate virtual hosts.
In /etc/nginx-sites-available/alpha:
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name alpha.com www.alpha.com;
  return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;

  root /var/www/html/alpha.com;
  index index.html index.htm;
}

In /etc/nginx/sites-available/beta:
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name beta.com www.beta.com;
  return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;

  root /var/www/html/beta.com;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}

I added in /etc/hosts:
127.0.1.1 alpha.com
127.0.1.1 beta.com

Every time I test beta in the browser, I get the content for alpha instead. Adding this to /etc/nginx/sites-available/beta did not make a difference:
location {
  proxy_pass http://www.beta.com/;
  root /var/www/html/beta.com;
  index index.html;
}

Adding this to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf broke the server ("[emerg] "proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here"):
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/html;

  location /dynamicabatherapy {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote-addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
  }
}

If I remove the symbolic link for alpha, remove all references to its URL, and move its source files, www.beta.com gives me "404 Not Found"
My questions is, first of all, can this be done (2 domains, 2 DNS, 1 server, sharing the same port)? If I put my local host in the browser, I eventually get a timeout error from alpha's DNS, even after disabling the domain (alpha) associated with that DNS. Do I have to migrate the 2nd domain to the same DNS as a subdomain for this to work?
If not, how do I direct each request from the router to the right server block?
And when it comes to the SSL certificate, can I have 2 certificates from different CAs, without migrating beta.com to Cloudflare, or do I need a single SAN certificate instead?

did you link them to sites-enabled?

Yes, I linked to sites-enabled, with "sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/beta /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/beta

Please add output of nginx -T to the question so we can see the full nginx configuration.

@Tero Ok the output is linked below ("alpha" is my existing website, "beta" is the website I'm trying to add "gamma" is another domain with no content registered with Cloudflare, of which "alpha" is actually a subdomain): https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/lf78sxyd8ks43ansh108t/_-Nginx-config.paper?rlkey=nmcbb9j2k8vrrjnwn5qgnea5b&dl=0

There is no virtual host alpha.com in your configuration. If you need to hide domain names, please use example.com and its subdomains.

@Tero My mistake, I had removed that symbolic link from sites-enabled while experimenting. I have updated this to include all config. So wow, there's a whole chunk of code I was not taking into account with /demo remaining in sites-enabled with "gamma" config. My "alpha" website is set up as a subdomain of "gamma" on the DNS, but I'm not currently serving anything on "gamma.com" Does that config need to stay there or should I just remove it?


My questions is, first of all, can this be done (2 domains, 2 DNS, 1 server, sharing the same port)?

Yes this can be done.
First of all, let's correct a few mistakes:

as it is stated in the documentation, the proxy_pass directive can only be set in a location block.
with this line you're basically asking Nginx to listen to himself: proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
you do not need to set any hostname in /etc/hosts

What you want to do is to register A records such as alpha.com & beta.com in your domain name servers so that they point to your Nginx server. Then, depending on what you want to serve on this server (simple files located on the server or a data stream from another server), you want to set a root directive or a proxy_pass directive in the correct virtual host file, under a location block, say location / { ...} by default.
Do no forget to test your configuration: nginx -t and to reload it: nginx -s reload.

TY. Ok, "proxy_pass" is already in a location block. I have already entered A records in each DNS. I have now removed the added lines from /etc/hosts. In /etc/nginx/sites-available/beta, location block is now:
location / {
proxy_pass http://www.beta.com;
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
Reloaded Nginx, and: "[emerg] host not found in upstream "www.beta.com" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dynamicabatherapy:17"

The error you now have is because your config points to the wrong upstream server. It is pointing to itself. Ask you this question: where is the data you want to serve ? Then read again the last paragraph of my answer.

The data is in /var/www/html/beta.com. According to the docs, "proxy_pass" takes a URI as an argument. I tried several adjustments to the location block in etc/nginx/sites-available/beta.
"root /var/www/html/beta.com" > browser timed out.
"proxy_pass http://112.0.0.1" [the localhost] > "404 Not Found"
"proxy_pass http://112.0.1.1." [for the device] > "Site can't be reached."
Under the impression that I do need to use "proxy_pass" for this, but apparently I'm not quite grasping what it's referring to, and even with alpha config removed, im not getting any response at all from Google Domains
